# Is there an equivalent NSLocalizedString() for reading values from different locales (not languages)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

I have an app that needs to read different values based on locale (country).

I was hoping that NSLocalizedString would do that for me but it only seems to work on language, not locale.

I could do it in code (NSLocale/NSLocaleCountryCode) but I'm hoping there's a more code-free way to go.

Is there some other function or method to achieve this?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLocalizedString is just a macro for the NSBundle method

`- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName`

with

`table = nil;`

(see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIDIHDH))

Instead of NSLocalizedString, you could create different table names based on your locale, then call

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *table = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyTable_%@", countryCode];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"YOUR_KEY" value:@"" tableName:table];
```

If that is too long for you, you could also wrap it into a macro again.